# Passing parameters between Spring-cloud-dataflow composite task

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I built a composite task in spring-cloud-dataflow. 

 It is working. 
Now i need to pass an output of my first task (FirstCloudTask) to second task (SUCCESS_TASK). 
How can i pass an input parameter to my send task on completion of my first task ? Ex: job_id, job_name, etc., from First task to Second task.

here is my DSL for composite task

```
FirstCloudTask 'FAILED'->FAILED_TASK && SUCCESS_TASK
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Task applications are intended to operate independently.

Though SCDF provides a mechanism (i.e., Composed Tasks) to orchestrate independent Tasks to be run as a directed-graph, there's no mechanism however to share or propagate information between the Tasks included in the graph. In other words, there's no out of the box opinions to solve for this requirement.

In practice, we have seen folks relying on external systems such as a database or message brokers to share information between the Tasks.